# It seems that there are folders in onedrive if opened from one note but such folders does not exist in normal onedrive

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-onedrive

I have 2 mysterious notebook I want to delete

If I open location from one note this is what I see

[image]

As you see there are 2 folders that most likely correspond to my notebook. systemdocumentation and systemdocumentation-jim-PC

However, if I open onedrive folder, the same folder on the web this is what I see

[image]

You see the folder systemdocumentation-jim-PC doesn't exist

You see the folder TestHello on both of the pictures? That is a folder I created for the very purpose of ensuring that this is indeed the same folder. If I create TestHello or change their name in onedrive or in onenote the folder is there.

So it seems that the folder where one note stores all the notes are hidden. My settings is to show hidden files.

Besides the onedrive folder I show you is opened in chrome. Those files are not shown even on the web.

Why?

This is what my onedrive folder in my computer looks like

[image]

As you see, neither systemdocumentation or systemdocumentation-Jim-PC shows up as folders.

Even though hidden folder is meant to be shown. I wonder why.

Comment: `systemdocumentation-jim-PC` does exist. It just doesn't appear as a folder. It has the OneNote icon instead. I am unsure why some appear as folders and why some appear as OneNote notebooks but this is not abnormal. I too have similar layouts where it appears as a folder locally but as a OneNote notebook in OneDrive. Unless you are unable to view the notebook using a local app or view it in Microsoft 365, there isn't a problem.

Comment: I can't view systemdocumentation-jim-PC. Not in onedrive folder in my computer. Not in online onedrive folder. I wonder if it's normal.

Comment: Does `systemdocumentation-jim-PC` open in OneNote (via both the desktop app and Microsoft 365 online)?

Comment: I also have multiple files on my OneDrive that are like what you are describing. I cannot open up the file unless it is opened by OneNote. I agree that OneNote files in their current form are a little opaque to the user ... unlike years from several years prior. Unless you are unable to open the notebook within OneNote, I wouldn't worry about it. I will concede this response isn't encouraging and I am not an expert on the matter. I am just relaying my similar experience. It would be great if a OneNote expert could chime in.

Comment: Take a look at the following location to see if you can access individual components of your notebook: `...\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneNote\16.0\Backup`

Comment: Onenote recoqnize a not whose name is systemdocumentation-jim-PC. However those folders do not show up in one drive.

So it's like a hidden folder that only one note app recognize.

The problem is the 2 folders are probably synced in ways that create copies. Maybe both are changed and there is a conflict. So I got two very similar one note. I should just move them but I can't because I can't see the folder.

Comment: @brian thanks for telling me that you have the same problem

Comment: I don't think it's a problem, per se. I think the current version of OneNote is designed so that you can't navigate via a typical folder hierarchy as you could with previous versions unless you go to `...\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneNote\16.0\Backup`. I think I would have preferred the MSFT design it such that you could navigate via a folder hierarchy but the current implementation is what it is and is not a problem with OneNote.